# Is there a way to specify JPA annotations for fields referencing entities with openapi-generator for Spring?

Tags: spring, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am trying to use [openapi-generator for Spring](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/) to generate the model to use in a SpringBoot application. But I cannot find a way to produce an entity class with a field referencing another entity, with JPA field annotation such as @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, or @ManyToMany.

Let's consider the following target model : a Customer entity references a User entity as a field.
I want to obtain the following Customer entity class :

```
@jakarta.persistence.Entity @jakarta.persistence.Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

  @JsonProperty("user")
  @jakarta.persistence.OneToOne
  private User user;
}
```

For Spring java code generation, I use maven, with openapi-generator-maven-plugin configured that way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../../openapi/openapi.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <output>${project.basedir}</output>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
</project>
```

I tried the following unsuccessful options in my openapi.yml file :

1. Using $ref directly to set the field datatype :

I tried that following openapi.yml file :

```
openapi: 3.0.2
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      description: ""
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          description: ""
          type: UUID
          x-field-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Id'
      x-class-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Entity @jakarta.persistence.Table(name
        = "users")'
    Customer:
      description: ""
      type: object
      properties:
        user:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
          description: ""
          x-field-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.OneToOne'
        id:
          description: ""
          type: UUID
          x-field-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Id'
      x-class-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Entity @jakarta.persistence.Table(name
        = "customers")'
```

As a result, openapi-generator for Spring generates both entity classes :

- User
- Customer, with a field named "user" of type User
  But in Customer, the field annotation @jakarta.persistence.OneToOne of Customer#user field is not generated.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4732) explains why : as $ref hides any other sibling element

2. Using allOf workaround

A workaround to avoid elements sibling to $ref to be ignored is suggested here : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4732. That gives the following openapi.yml variant :

```
openapi: 3.0.2
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      description: ""
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          description: ""
          type: UUID
          x-field-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Id'
      x-class-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Entity @jakarta.persistence.Table(name
        = "users")'
    Customer:
      description: ""
      type: object
      properties:
        user:
          anyOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
          description: ""
          x-field-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.OneToOne'
        id:
          description: ""
          type: UUID
          x-field-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Id'
      x-class-extra-annotation: '@jakarta.persistence.Entity @jakarta.persistence.Table(name
        = "customers")'
```

Then openapi-generator for Spring generates 3 entity classes :

- User
- Customer, with a field user of type CustomerUser
- CustomerUser
  In Customer, the field annotation @jakarta.persistence.OneToOne for the field Customer#user is generated, but this field has a wrong type, and I don't want to have the extra CustomerUser entity class generated.

Does anyone know a way to generate theses entity classes correctly with JPA annotation ?

Comment: As a complement, I found that feature request for openapi-generator https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/5312. It introduces the possibility to configure JPA annotations in Spring openapi-generator. But I did not see that specific point in this ticket...